# How do I create a Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am working on my assignment.  It has 8 tables. Each table has a primary key.  What do i do to generate a foreign key to a table?

My reason for asking is that  when I generate a primary key, a key symbol appears on the left.

What do i do to make something a foreign key?

Comment: what platform / tool are you using ?

Comment: Could have been resolved by a simple query in google ...

Comment: VisualStudio 2008 and MS SQL server Management Studio Express

Comment: A foreign key IS NOT a modified version of a primary key.  It's something separate.  You put the primary key in one table, and establish a separate foreign key in a second table that references the primary key.  For instance, CustomerID in the Customers table would have a primary key, but CustomerID in the Orders table would be a foreign key _referencing_ the primary key in the Customers table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-foreign-keys.html) for the subject -- you might wanna take a look at it. Basically, here's an example of what you do:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `table1_id` INT(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES table_1(`id`)
)
```

This should basically make `table_2.table1_id` reference `table_1.id` as a foreign key.

Comment: so.. here, id is a primary key.. and when i want to make it a foreign key, the name and the data type should be the same ? is it? and the SQL will automatically make it a forign key? is dis so?

Comment: id is the primary key, and on the other table, it has a field of the same type, using the REFERENCES keyword and it references table_1(id), which is our primary key. So now, table_1.table1_id is related to table_1.id

Answer (score 0):

The SQL to add a foreign key between table1 (the referencing table) and table2 (the primary table) is:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY table1_table2_FK 
    REFERENCES table2 (intId) ON (intTable2Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is arising from the fact that you think a **foreign key** is a modified version of a **primary key**.  It is not, it is a separate item.

For instance, CustomerID in the Customers table would have a primary key, but CustomerID in the Orders table would be a **foreign key** referencing (pointing back to) the primary key in the Customers table.

In the Customers table, the **primary key** serves to uniquely identify each customer.  In the Orders table the **foreign key** on CustomerID serves to guarantee that each order belongs to an existing record from the customer table.

You can have the **primary key** without establishing any **foreign keys**, it will still serve it's role in identifying records.  But you cannot have a **foreign key** without a **primary key** in a different table (or, in rare occurrences, in the same table) because the **primary key** name is part of the definition of the **foreign key**.  And you can have as many **foreign keys** as you want in different tables (in rare cases in the same tables) pointing back to a single **primary key**.